# SQL Server Auto generate update scripts without compare (target database unknown)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing this post I because I need to generate automated update scripts to update tables, columns, etc. to a target database. Our issue is that we do not have access to the target database, and therefore, we can not perform a comparison. Is there any tool that would allow me to generate some sort of "generic" script that would update any database, regardless of its current structure?

Comment: Just to clarify... do you want to generate `UPDATE` scripts or `ALTER` (in your words, "update") tables, columns, etc?

Comment: I guess you could create all your tables with a temp name, insert the old data into the new table given new columns are nullable, drop the old tables & rename the new ? Just from the top of my head..